# Machine Learning applied to chess tutoring software

Tags: machine-learning, chess

This may belong in the chess SE community but I am looking at the question from a programming perspective rather than pedagogical or even chess perspective.

I know of several studies and attempts to create chess engines which use some variant of machine learning to **play** chess (most of which are usually studies in the subject, rather than attempts to trump the brute force method, which is so far superior to other methods), but few attempts to apply machine learning to chess pedagogy.

One of the main reasons for a chess coach/tutor is the personalized attention and direction that the tutor provides. Is it then possible to create a chess program which uses machine learning to generate personalized "lessons" for the user based on their strengths and weaknesses?

The lessons need not be complex, even generating relevant positions from a database and asking the user to "solve" them, then giving a line or variation in response to an answer (correct or incorrect) is a great deal of instruction (for, even without explanations, the variations can often suffice)

The main questions are:

1. How would the software be able to guage the user's skill level? (This is really where the ML algorithm would have to come in)
2. How can the software determine the difficulty or "appropriateness" of a test position? e.g suppose the software determines that the user has difficulty with tactical positions, (an issue most amateur players have) how can the program choose a position (from its database of games, lets suppose) with approriate tactical difficulty?
3. Finally, how will the software percieve and adapt to improvement by the user?

I apologize if this question is to abstract or theoritical for SO, if so, I will move it elsewhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would start by having the chess program dump out statistics to a CSV or JSON file showing:

> 1. Which pieces were moved and how often
> 2. How many moves it took until a checkmate took place
> 3. How many games over what period of time.
> 4. How many pieces captured over time. etc

You have a tremendous amount of flexibility over picking you data points of interest or features that will be used to train your ML algorithm. Once you have these data points together and a data file that can be made available to your algorithm, you can begin to train it and see what predictive results you get. Then will need to tweak your experiment until you get results that are indeed useful.

Here is a Python based Random Forrest algorithm along with [a tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/forums/t/2299/getting-started-python-sample-code-random-forest) to get you started:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt

def main():
    #create the training & test sets, skipping the header row with [1:]
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('Data/train.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]    
    target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
    train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
    test = genfromtxt(open('Data/test.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]

    #create and train the random forest
    #multi-core CPUs can use: rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=2)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    rf.fit(train, target)

    savetxt('Data/submission2.csv', rf.predict(test), delimiter=',', fmt='%f')

if __name__=="__main__"
```

This could be quite interesting when you get it going. Getting the program to begin to anticipate weaknesses in a player would depend on what data you choose to collect.

Good luck.